# Is it possible to use multiprocessing in a module

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing

My python code (python3) sticks and never stops when I use multiprocessing as a separate module probably because of `if __name__=='__main__'` issue. My machine is Macbook but I am running the code under docker container. Is there any way to use multiprocessing in a module?

**inside module**

```
from multiprocessing import Process
    
class MultiProcessing:
    def printing(a):
       print(a)

    def run(self, a):
        with Pool(processes=self.cpuCore) as pool:
            partial_gp = functools.partial(self.printing, a=a)
            full_result = pool.map(partial_gp)
        return full_result
```

**inside main.py**

```
import MultiProcessing

MP = MultiProcessing()
result = MP.run(a)
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76256527/edit) to include your code, preferably a [mcve].  As it stands right now, your question does not contain enough detail for anyone to be able to answer your question with certainty.

Comment: It can be done, but it's tricky, because you don't control the initialization done by the main program.  If they invoke your class every time, you will have an infinitely cascading process tree.

Comment: What do you mean "in a module"? As a external module/library to be distributed and used by a lot of program (and programmers)? In such case, think about an API (and that it is very tricky to do correctly): you may not want to restrict user the ability to use multiprocessor for other tasks.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you may already know most of this, but it may be useful to others:

The problem occurs when the platform you are running under is using the *spawn* method of creating child processes, such as Windows. In this case the address space of every child process is initialized by running a new instance of the Python interpreter in each child process and recompiling all modules that have been loaded so far. This means that anything at global scope in these modules will be executed, e.g. import statements, global variable definitions, class definitions, function definitions, etc.

Since your `run` method, which creates new child processes, is *not* at global scope, it will not automatically be executed in the child processes that constitute the multiprocessing pool being created. So far so good. However, any code at global scope that either *directly* or *indirectly* calls this method is a potential problem. An example of *indirectly* would be a statement at global scope that calls a function and that function *directly* or *indirectly* invokes the `run` method (note the recursion in my definition). Here is an example:

**main.py**

```py
def foo():
    import MultiProcessing

    MP = MultiProcessing()
    result = MP.run(a)

foo() # indirectly invokes MultiProcessing.run
```

The above call to `foo`, which is at global scope, must only be executed once, i.e. in the main process. Assuming **main.py** is the script being invoked, then `__name__` will be `'__main__'` in the main process and `'__mp__main__'` in the child processes. Since we only want to execute this call in the main process, we should code instead:

```py
def foo():
    import MultiProcessing

    MP = MultiProcessing()
    result = MP.run(a)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo()
```

The original definition of `foo` can remain unchanged. But if the above code were not in **main.py**, but rather **module.py**, then the check should be instead modified:

```py
def foo():
    import MultiProcessing

    MP = MultiProcessing()
    result = MP.run(a)

if __name__ == '__module__':
    foo()
```

The bottom line is that any code *at global scope* that invokes directly or indirectly `MultiProcessing.run` must be executed *conditionally* by first checking the current value of `'__name__'` for either `__main__` (if this code is in the script being executed without the Python -m flag) or otherwise for `'__module_name__'` where *module_name* is the name of an imported module